# What is the relationship between the concept of service in docker-compose and the concept of container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In docker-compose, we can define `service` attribute `image`, or we can `build` an image from a dockerfile.
It seems that `service` is the same with `container` which is also a running instance of the based `image`.

So what is the difference between `service` and `container`?

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually a service and a container are completely different things.

- A container is a standardised wrapper around an isolated process.
- A service is a mechanism to provide access to capabilities (running software) via a formal interface.

Further, in docker-compose, a service can have 0..n instances, where n defaults to 1 and can be overridden. Access over HTTP will be load-balanced by compose and services will be registered in a registry that allows other services to look them up by name for access (dns).

There are other differences, such as the default placement of services on a shared network. And, another difference is that compose is declarative where 'docker run' is imperative. There is a strong preference in the industry for the former.

Comment: IMHO, Compose is used in a single host, compared with Swarm which are is to deploy our application in a cluster.  Can we have more than 1 service instance in a single host?

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption seems correct. [Docker states](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#compose-and-docker-compatibility-matrix) that they follow the compose-spec for Cloud Native Applications. According to the [compose-spec](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#services-top-level-element):

*Services are defined by a Docker image and set of runtime arguments. All containers within a service are identically created with these arguments.*

Functionally, they should be the same. docker-compose files are an easier way to define how a container should be run (compared to providing long commands to the `docker` CLI). Services are a concept used by `docker-compose` to abstract some computing resource that can be scaled and replaced independently from other components.

All credit due the [compose-spec/spec.md](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md) doc. This is the best description I've read of what they meant these to be.